# Angular scope variable is empty in another function that fires on an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Service**

```
angular.module('tested-user')
.service('tests', function($http, $q){
    this.getTests = $q.when($http.get('http://localhost:3000/tests.json'));});
```

**Controller**

```
tests.getTests.then(function(data){
        noOfTests = data.data.tests.length;
        $scope.testsForSearch = data.data.tests;
        while($scope.testsForSearch.length){
            if($scope.testsForSearch.length > 1 )
            {
                $scope.tests.push(testsForSearch.splice(0,2));
            }
            else{
                $scope.tests.push(testsForSearch.splice(0,1));
            }
        }
        // data is empty here also
        console.log(data);
    }
```

**Function in the Controller that uses the scope variable**

```
$scope.search = function(){
        console.log($scope.testsForSearch.tests);
        $scope.testsForSearch.tests.forEach(function(test){
            if(test.name.search($scope.searchInput)){
                $scope.tests.push(test);
            }
        });
    }
```

The scope.search function will be called on a click event. For some reason, scope.testsForSearch is empty in the 'search' function, But has data in the views and in the place where the 'tests.getTests' function is called.

Comment: Wierdly, the 'data' object returned from the http request , as indicated in the second block of code under 'controller' is also empty. But has data when it is assigned to $scope.testsForSearch.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but data is not containing a value, but the "promise" value. Data.data is the real return value of the request... Or even data.data is empty?

Comment: Your main options here are assign the variables to a non scoped variable, change your standard function definition to an arrow function definition. Or pass your variables to the function as a parameter otherwise it will try to run it out of scope

Comment: @Binvention can you give me a code snippet?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should change in the controller this part 
testsForSearch = data.data.tests; 
In 
$scope.testsForSearch = data.data.tests;

Otherwise it will not be visible outside the controller as it's a local variable, not a scoped one

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake when i copy pasted the code. I used a scope variable only.

Comment: Yes I used a scope variable only. It was mistake when I copy pasted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you have used the http.get that returns a promise, inside an $q That should return a promise, as it's used to async invoke methods (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) 
The first question is why? 
Try either to remove the $q or to handle one more then construct on data

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that function(){} has its own variable scope in JavaScript meaning everything defined outside of it wont necessarily be defined wishing it. The main one in your case is the angular $scope variable. I'm not sure exactly why this is but local variables are defined within the function meaning

```
$scope.testing=5;
$scope.run=function(){
      console.log($scope.testing);
};
```

Won't work because it's not defined in the function  but this will work

```
$scope.testing=5;
var testing=$scope.testing;
$scope.run=function(){
    console.log(testing);
}
```

And because of angular  data binding when you change the testing variable inside the function it will change the $scope.testing variable outside of the function.

And although I haven't done it personally you could try doing things like assigning a local variable to $scope like this `var scope=$scope;`which would probably work. Also arrow functions which look like his (parameter)=>{console.log(parameter);} don't create their own scope the only problem being they are anonymous functions meaning they don't have names so you can't refer to them later because they don't have a name to refer to them by. The. The other thing you could fiddle with if you want is passing $scope as a parameter to your function although I imagine that would be quite difficult to get working and it wouldn't work at all with success handler. The code above does work though anything else you'll just have to fiddle with

Comment: In some other functions yes. But it depends on how you run them

Comment: When you run the function as a success handed to an async request it tends not to work. Local variables seem to be more reliable